# Mysql, use another table's field value in where clause with regexp?

Tags: mysql, regex

I was gonna do this the brute-force way, but am wondering if there's a more elegant/efficient solution:

Take a simple table, PEOPLE:

```
RecNum    Category     Name
1001      A            Alice
1002      A            Bob
1003      B            Charlie
1004      C            Doug
1005      A            Ernie
```

There's another table NEWS that's basically just a text field with optional inline tagging:

```
RecNum     NewsText
201        Blah blah {p1003}
202        Blah blah blah
203        Blah {p1005}
204        {p1002} blah blah
205        Blah {p1003} blah
```

The '{p####}' is used in internal parsing: the 'p' means it's the PEOPLE table and the '####' is the RecNum of the PEOPLE record and the tag is replaced with the Name...so, when displayed, NEWS RecNum 201 would show 'Blah blah Charlie.'

What I need to do is, given a PEOPLE Category value, find the Distinct Count of the NEWS records that contain the '{p####}' RecNums of all PEOPLE with the given Category.

For instance, for the above 3 Categories, the returns should be:

```
Category A: 2 (from NEWS records 203 and 204)
Category B: 1 (need distinct count, even though Charlie (1003) shows up in 2 NEWS records (201 & 205))
Category C: 0 (not found)
```

I'm trying to do this with Regexp, but cannot see how I can tell it what to look for (the RecNum of each record with the given Category)

Is this even possible? Is Regexp not the way to do this?

Any assistance/guidance appreciated!

edit:
...or would it be easier just to grab the whole NEWS table and parse it in php?

-G

Comment: Yes, That's possible by both way PHP and Mysql...

Comment: If you try to handle this through PHP that would be much better

Comment: Do the parsing before you insert the data; insert the mapping into another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without regular expression.

```
SELECT count(distinct(people.RecNum)) from people
LEFT JOIN news on news.NewsText like concat('%{p', people.RecNum , '}%')
WHERE news.NewsText like concat('%{p', people.RecNum , '}%')
AND people.Category='A'
```

Comment: That did it Bansi..many thnx!!

It's amazing how one can get into a particular mindset -- wanting to count the NEWS items with RegExp-- when it makes much more sense to count the PEOPLE who match the NEWS items without RegExp...much gratitude for breaking me out of my preconceived conditions...